# Is there a client that can export to Excel detailed information about transactions?

Tags: client

I need a client that has a feature of exporting **full information** about transactions in an Excel or CSV file. By full information I mean sender, receiver, amount, time, confirmation status.

In other words, I want the information that is related to my addresses. If it has multiple sources and affects several address that belong to me I would like to see one line per address. So I want just to see as clearly as it's possible what happend with my address, when and where from/to the coins moved. Just like when you do your simple accounting. In Qt client I cannot see the information about sender in exported file. Is there any client that has this functionality?

Comment: Bear in mind that a transaction can contain multiple inputs and outputs, e.g. http://blockchain.info/tx/68bb6bf43d6bbb90c77f08c4de4bdddae6ca35abff2e25db4bdce7f88c576bf2. So is this really want you want or are you just trying to get some particular info about a transaction?

Comment: @cdm9002 Thanks for the information. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use blockchain.info to get information about your address, then use the Export History option in the dropdown menu (slightly confusingly marked 'Filter') to export to CSV.

It doesn't do exactly what you ask for, but has one line per transaction. I'm having difficulty picturing how it would work with one line per address.

The address for querying addresses is https://blockchain.info/address/1youraddressgoeshere

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Export to CSV feature on Electrum.

You can import the addresses you want to check and export info from.

Menu bar > Export > History